# How to display a dialog when a button is clicked using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to display a dialog to the bottom right corner of the page on clickin a button using react and typescript.

There is a button named "Add" in ListComponent. when clicking that button dialog which is the DialogComponent should be rendered.

Below is how the ListComponent and DialogComponent looks

```
function ListComponent() {
    const onAddClicked = () => {
        //what to be done
    }
    return (
        <button onClick={onAddClicked}> Add</button>
    );
 }

 function DialogComponent() {
     return (
         <Wrapper> Dialog </Wrapper>
     )
 }
```

Now i cannot call DailogComponent within ListComponent as it would push the layout of the page.

So i want to call this DailogComponent within MainComponent which is something like below

```
function Main () {
    return (
        <ListComponent>
            //some props
        </ListComponent>
    )
 }
```

I am new to using react with typescript. How can i do this. could someone provide some insights into this. thanks.

Comment: You can simply use the Modal component like in this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jz2v8v2rlw?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: thanks since this is  a functional component i cannot use this.state and this.setState and pass it to higherorder component Main from child ListComponent. How can i do it using react hooks or any other way than this.state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely want to use fixed positioning (and possibly some increased z-index, if necessary) to display a dialog box at the bottom right of the screen. This will "break" it out of being rendered "inline" with your content.

At a minimum you should utilize the following CSS rules

```
position: fixed;
bottom: <M>; // M units from the bottom
right: <N>; // N units from the right
```

[image: Edit green-morning-pn9te]

The linked codesandbox sets this Dialog class style and component

CSS

```
.dialog {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

JSX

```
const Dialog = ({ showDialog, text }) =>
  showDialog ? <div className="dialog">{text}</div> : null;
```

How you toggle the display state of the dialog is up to you.

**EDIT:** Full code with a demo `ListComponent`

```
const Dialog = ({ showDialog, text }) =>
  showDialog ? <div className="dialog">{text}</div> : null;

const ListComponent = ({ data, toggleDialog }) =>
  data.map((el, i) => (
    <div key={i}>
      <button type="button" onClick={toggleDialog}>
        {el}
      </button>
    </div>
  ));

export default function App() {
  const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState();

  const toggleDialog = () => setShowDialog(s => !s);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <button type="button" onClick={toggleDialog}>
        Toggle Dialog in Main
      </button>

      <h2>List Component</h2>
      <ListComponent data={["A", "B", "C"]} toggleDialog={toggleDialog} />

      <Dialog showDialog={showDialog} text="I'm a dialog" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is essentially applying [Lifted State](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). State and mutators are lifted to a common ancestor of components interested in either displaying the state, or updating. State and state updaters are passed as props to children.

Comment: thanks. Here in your example button being clicked is easily accessible in the AppComponent. In my case i have it within ListComponent..how can i pass it from that component to Main so the Dialog can access it.

Comment: @someuser2491 Pass a callback function to `ListComponent` to attach to button `onClick` handlers to open dialog in the main component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a callback in order to display the dialog box from Main function.
Below is an example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Modal from "react-modal";

const Main = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ListComponent onAddClickedProps={handleAddClick} />

      <DialogComponent isOpen={isOpen} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const ListComponent = ({ onAddClickedProps }) => {
  const onAddClicked = () => {
    onAddClickedProps();
  };

  return <button onClick={onAddClicked}> Add</button>;
};

const DialogComponent = ({ isOpen }) => {
  return (
    <Modal isOpen={isOpen}>
      <div>I am a modal</div>
    </Modal>
  );
};

render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[React-modal-example-on-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-modal-with-state-qfxmm)